# Building a query to auto add a new column based on a function with Microsoft Power BI

Tags: csv, powerbi

Can you please help me with how I can add a new column in my data in a power bi query? If i try to manual add a new column with the following function everything is working great. But I want to be able to build a query so I dont have to do it manually every month I need to print a report.

```
Size = IF(ISNUMBER(Data[Home Size]),CEILING(Data[Home Size], 10)-9&" - "&CEILING(Data[Home Size],10)))
```

When using query editor in power bi, I got something like this:

```
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i44FAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table []),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Size", each IF(ISNUMBER(Data[Home Size]),CEILING(Data[Home Size], 10)-9&" - "&CEILING(Data[Home Size],10)))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

And I get the following error:

```
Expression error: The name 'IF' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be trying to use DAX or Excel formula syntax. Power BI Queries use a completely different syntax - e.g "if ... then ... else ...".  The column references in Power BI Queries do not include table names, e.g. just `[Home Size]`

Search for examples etc using "Power Query" which was the name of the Excel Add-In which was the parent of this component of Power BI.

Here's the root of the doco for this language, which is often called "Power Query Function language" or (rarely) "M":

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt211003.aspx

It's bizarrely hard to find the actual spec for if-then-else - it's buried in the "Formula Language Specification" PDF with a cursory 4 line explanation, that doesn't mention that it can be nested...